# Just one pie in report chart if parameter values are equal

Tags: charts, jasper-reports

Was created pie 3d chart. It has several params. For example, one of them call "errors" and another - "success". Both is Integer. If values are different, for example 10 and 9, all work fine, but if values are equal, it draw like one pie, and in label expression writed only one value.

[image]

In this image I set 10 errors and 10 success, but as can be seen, *JasperReports* draw just 10 success.

I check it in *iReport* and by generation report in *Java*, but results was same.

One more example.

```xml
<parameter name="access" class="java.lang.Number"/> set 10
<parameter name="configChange" class="java.lang.Number"/> set 10
<parameter name="creating" class="java.lang.Number"/> set 5
<parameter name="deleting" class="java.lang.Number"/> set 10
<parameter name="updating" class="java.lang.Number"/> set 5
<parameter name="objRequest" class="java.lang.Number"/> set 7
<parameter name="unknown" class="java.lang.Number"/> set 8
```

Result:

[image]

jrxml-file:

```xml
             <pie3DChart>
                <chart isShowLegend="true" renderType="draw" theme="default">
                    <reportElement uuid="1ea2fe12-8478-48a3-8a16-828cb17bc242" positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="50" width="430" height="280" backcolor="#CCFFFF"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <pieDataset>
                    <pieSeries>
                        <keyExpression><![CDATA[$P{errors}]]></keyExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$P{errors}]]></valueExpression>
                        <labelExpression><![CDATA["Error"]]></labelExpression>
                    </pieSeries>
                    <pieSeries>
                        <keyExpression><![CDATA[$P{success}]]></keyExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$P{success}]]></valueExpression>
                        <labelExpression><![CDATA["Success"]]></labelExpression>
                    </pieSeries>
                </pieDataset>
                <pie3DPlot depthFactor="0.2">
                    <plot backgroundAlpha="0.1" foregroundAlpha="0.6">
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="0" color="#FF0000"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="1" color="#0066FF"/>
                    </plot>
                    <itemLabel/>
                </pie3DPlot>
            </pie3DChart>
```

Comment: could you insert your jrxml-file as well? You may be grouping them on the value instead of the category

Comment: Thanks for replay. Added path of jrxml-file. About grouping: I just use pieSeries with corresponding keyExpression and valueExpression

Comment: Sorry, I realized my mistake, and it is obvious: use value as the key and they are equal.